# обход ошибки возращения из пустого тега xpath

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть страница, с которой беру два значения, одно это статическое мак-адрес, второе динамическое, это дата и время. Иногда бывает что что тег с датой и временем пустой, т.е. на странице вместо даты и времени пустота. Так вот, xpath в таком случае не отрабатывает, при попытке запуска скрипта появляется ошибка.
Как можно сделать что бы ошибка не возникала? Или в это пустое значение что то записать...

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

a = 'HOSTNAME'

response = requests.get('URL')
parsed_body = html.fromstring(response.text)

b1 = parsed_body.xpath('//html/body/table/tbody/tr[356]/td[1]/text()')[0]
c1 = parsed_body.xpath('//html/body/table/tbody/tr[356]/td[2]/text()')[0]
print(a, b1, c1)
```

IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обрабатывайте исключение `IndexError`. Если все хорошо записывайте в `c1` дату и время, а иначе, если возникает исключение, записывайте в `c1` что-нибудь другое, например сообщение об ошибке.

```
try:
    c1 = parsed_body.xpath('//html/body/table/tbody/tr[356]/td[2]/text()')[0]
except IndexError:
    c1 = default #его зададите сами
```

Answer (score 0):

@Звягинцев Денис Спасибо, работает. Но чуть спать не ушёл из за ошибок, оказывается у вас с1 были на русской раскладке написаны =)) вот так сделал:

```
try:
    b1 = parsed_body.xpath('//html/body/table/tbody/tr[49]/td[1]/text()')[0] # mac-address
    c1 = parsed_body.xpath('//html/body/table/tbody/tr[49]/td[2]/text()')[0] # datetime
except IndexError:
    now = datetime.now()
    c1 = now.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S") #его зададите сами
    print(a, b1, c1)
```

Comment: Какой смысл в этом ответе? Чем он отличается от моего?

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и/или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Звягинцев Денис ни чем, можно было и не отвечать да, просто показал как на основе вашего примера решил проблему.